# error in R.java file

Tags: android

How do I solve this error in my R.java file. I have cleaned the project and set the resources to UTF-8.

```
public static final int editText-contact=0x7f050073;
```

it underlines the "dash"(hi-fen) in red. I have tried to edit it but the logcat stated:
[2014-05-28 15:46:42 - MIPS_HC] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!

what other ways that i could remove the error??

I got this error when i changed my @+id/RelativeLayout1 to @+id/addnewadmin. I also changed the ids for my individual components like @+id/textview01 to @+id/textview01_firstN.

Is that a wrong move to do because I am still a beginner in android programming. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: hyphen (**-**) is a FORBIDDEN CHARACTER. Rename `editText-contact` to `editText_contact`

Comment: why do you need to edit R.java file

Comment: I tried but it will automatically change back to the error code. @DerGolem

Comment: It happened on its own. I had never opened the R.java file. @Raghunandan

Comment: Delete R.java and do a Project/Clean

Comment: What are the steps to do Project/clean? and will the R.java file appear back again once I do that? Because I did the android tools -> clean lint markers.

Comment: I have solved my error. It was a typo in one of my xml files. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read [Java naming conventions again](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). You don't use a hyphen in names.

Simply Replace:

```
editText-contact
```

with:

```
editText_contact
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It will automatically revert back to the error code. @abdulfatir

Comment: That's because you cannot edit R.java manually. Try renaming the name of the text field *contact*.

Comment: How do I do that? @abdulfatir

Comment: i have solved my error. there was a typo in one of the xml files. thanks.